# MySQL server refuses remote connection when under high load

Tags: mysql

When my MySQL server is under high load from the local machine it doesn't accept any remote connections. When load is normal it connects without any issues, but under high load neither a MySQL nor telnet connection works, while local connections are fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add the error or refuse message you get? Or does the connection just time out? Are you connecting as `root` from localhost during the event? MySQL has limit for number of concurrent connections, but keeps one slot reserved for the root account to fix things when needed.

Comment: What are the values of `max_connections` and `Max_used_connections`?

Comment: @jkavalik It just hangs indefinitely, there is no error. I am aware of that, but my max_connections is 10000 and it's nowhere near that. I am able to connect with both root and a regular user on the localhost.

Comment: @RickJames 10000 `max_connections`, 631 `max_used_connections`

Comment: Are you running a hosted service?  I heard of one that drops `max_connections` when the load gets too high.  (I have 4-letter words for describing them.)

Comment: @nebkat does the machine respond to new network requests (ping, ssh etc) when there is the high load? (to check if it is mysql not responding or network/OS problem)

Comment: @RickJames No, dedicated

Comment: @jkavalik Yes, I use SSH to manage to manage the server

Comment: @nebkat can you simulate it in a test environment? If you can or next time it happens, check maybe netstat and similar tools (tcpdump?) to see if the connections are going to the machine at all and if they are just being ignored by mysql.